# fetch response of 1-9 digit from keypad phones in react-native or node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

1. A message sent to public through my application .
2. One who get that message had to response by typing 1 or 2 or any number in between 0-9.
3. Here comes main problem to receive or fetch those digit from their response message and use them in my react-native application.
    I will be glad if anyone can give a proper solution for it in react-native or node.js. Solution in another language will be accepted . Thanks for your efforts.